# Jenkinsfile Declarative Pipeline - capture all checkout scm output

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm writing a Jenkinsfile which begins as such:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'ec2-slave'
    }
    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
            steps {
                checkout scm
            }
        }
...
```

I would like to capture the output of the `checkout scm` call because I need to use the git-related information in subsequent steps.

This step of course runs wonderfully, producing output such as this:

```
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Checkout SCM)
[Pipeline] checkout
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url xxxxxxxxx # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from xxxxxxxxx
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials jenkins ssh key
 > git fetch --tags --progress xxxxxxxxx +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
Seen branch in repository origin/master
Seen 2 remote branches
 > git tag -l # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 10214b72d4c1f2c69444cc79a1af7ecc7f033349 (origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 10214b72d4c1f2c69444cc79a1af7ecc7f033349
 > git rev-list 10214b72d4c1f2c69444cc79a1af7ecc7f033349 # timeout=10
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Checkout)
[Pipeline] checkout
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url xxxxxxxxx # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from xxxxxxxxx
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials jenkins ssh key
 > git fetch --tags --progress xxxxxxxxx +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
Seen branch in repository origin/master
Seen 2 remote branches
 > git tag -l # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 10214b72d4c1f2c69444cc79a1af7ecc7f033349 (origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 10214b72d4c1f2c69444cc79a1af7ecc7f033349
```

Is there an intended method of capturing and/or referencing previous pipeline steps?

Comment: For what its worth I'm converting this Jenkinsfile from freestyle syntax. I've been able to "reference" previous steps by saving an `sh` call to a variable, for example. Not sure how to accomplish the same thing with `checkout scm`...I'm sure it's a simple solution but I'm still learning a lot about Groovy and Jenkinsfiles

Comment: I also tried this in a `script {}` block, which is producing odd output:
`checkout scm`

`echo "${scm.dump()}"`

This produces a map with a bunch of `null` values which doesn't do much for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a script step, execute the checkout with the git installed on the OS and capture the output:

```
script {
  GIT_CLONE = sh (
    script: 'git clone xxxxxxxxx',
    returnStdout: true
  ).trim()
  echo "git clone output: ${GIT_CLONE}"
}
```

Comment: That might be my only option, as I've had to resort to script blocks like that in other portions of my Jenkinsfile, though I was hoping there was a way to do so otherwise in this instance.

Answer (score 2):

The arbitrary pipeline script works in declarative pipeline

```
pipeline {
    agent any
stages {
    stage ('download') {
        steps {
            script {
                def scmInfo = checkout scm
                println "GIT_COMMIT " + scmInfo.GIT_COMMIT
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing was just adding an additional script step to the stage in which I needed those git variables.

```
       steps {
            script {
                GIT_COMMIT = sh (
                    script: 'git rev-parse HEAD',
                    returnStdout: true
                ).trim()

                GIT_URL = sh (
                    script: 'git config --get remote.origin.url',
                    returnStdout: true
                ).trim()
            }
        }
```

Comment: For the URL, you have to tell Jenkins where to checkout from, do you not? Seems like you could just set an environment variable at the beginning of your jenkinsfile, then use that in the checkout step and where ever else you need it.